# Multiple external data folders in R package

Tags: r, package

Can we have more than 1 external data folder in a R package.

I have been trying to do that but every time I build and install the package the other data folders are not included

Please let me know if any one knows a solution.

I am trying to build an R Rcpp package with multiple external data folders.

Comment: [R-exts 1.1.6](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages) covers what you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Put your folders in this structure:

```
pkg -- inst -- extdata -- folder1
                       -- folder2
                       -- folder3
```

and you can have as many as you like.

Comment: You are saying with in the package folder have the inst and with in the inst have the extdata

Comment: Yes, that much is mandated.  See `Writing R Extensions` at the R home page, search for `inst` and `extdata`.